# How to check if hardware clock is in UTC or Local time

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, bios, time

From what I've read the `hwclock -r` command only returns the time in local time no matter how it is set. I think `hwclock --utc` or `hwclock --localtime` will change the clock to UTC or localtime. But I don't want to change it; I want to know how it is currently set.

So how can I check if my hardware clock is set to UTC time or local time?

Comment: Check your BIOS setup. The computer's time is usually set here.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? What does `grep -i utc /etc/default/rcS` say?

Comment: @muru that command returned `UTC=no` so I assume it was changing it based on the localtime.  I changed that to `UTC=yes` and now the clock is working properly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 and later uses `systemd` as the default init system and includes the `timedatectl` program.  Running `timedatectl` will output:

```
      Local time: Tue 2016-02-02 09:47:54 MST
  Universal time: Tue 2016-02-02 16:47:54 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2016-02-02 16:47:54
       Time zone: America/Denver (MST, -0700)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

`RTC time` is the hardware clock. Compare it to the Local time and Universal times returned by `timedatectl` to determine how the hardware clock is set.

`RTC in local TZ: no` means the hardware clock is interpreted as UTC

`RTC in local TZ: yes` means the hardware clock is interpreted as local time

#### To switch using `timedatectl`

`sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 0` sets RTC to UTC

`sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` sets RTC to local time

#### Switch using config file

Setting the `UTC=` setting in `/etc/default/rcS` will change how the system interprets the hardware clock (`UTC=yes` or `UTC=no`).

Comment: +1 for this answer being simple and does not require `sudo`

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo hwclock --debug
```

Gives you the unmodified time before spitting out the interpreted (local or UTC) answer.

Comment: This was what I was hoping for thank you.  The man pages weren't very descriptive for that option so I wasn't sure what it did.

Comment: `timedatectl` is better, you dont need `sudo` for it

Comment: @FriarTuck what is the correct answer is totally up to you, no judgement over it

Comment: I certainly don't mind =)

Comment: how does this command helps? I cant see any line that says clock is in UTC

Comment: @edwardtorvalds It does output the hardware clock as read without changes and I could tell it was not the localtime.

Comment: If your system does not have timedatectl, this is your best bet (for the googlers here)